# Kaminari RoutingError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kaminari

I have 2 models docs and categories.

The relations are:

- a doc belongs to one category.
- a category has many docs.

I want to paginate over all docs and docs from a specific category. Here is what i did with kaminari readme in routes.rb (well, am not a rails guru yet)

```
   resources :docs do
     get 'page/:page', :action => :index, :on => :collection
   end
   match '/doc/',                   to: 'Docs#index',     :as => :docs

   resources :category_docs do
     get 'page/:page', :action => :category, :on => :collection
   end
   match '/doc/category/:category', to: 'Docs#category',  :as => :docs_category
```

The pagination for all docs works fine, but category pagination gives a RoutingError at this line in my view

```
   <%= paginate @category_docs, :left => 2, :right => 2 %>
```

Here's docs controller

```
   def category
     @title = "Title"
     category = nil
     if params[:category] == "a"
       category = Category.find_by_title( "aa" )
     # code omitted
     elsif params[:category] == "e"
       category = Category.find_by_title( "ff" )
   end

   if category != nil
       @category_docs = category.docs.page( params[ :page ] ).per( 10 )
   else
       @category_docs = Doc.order("updated_at DESC").page( params[ :page ] ).per( 10 )
   end
```

Where am i wrong? 
Should i switch to will_paginate?
Or just throw out this code and do something else?

Answer (score 0):

```
match '/doc/category/:category', to: 'Docs#category',  :as => :docs_category
```

Shouldn't that be `:category_docs`, not `docs_category`? I don't know the kaminari gem in detail, but when you call `paginate @category_docs`, I think by default that's what it will look for.

Comment: Can you post the RoutingError you get?

Comment: No luck. Everything's the same

Comment: The Routing error was "could not find a route to controller + action". Couldnt find an answer, installed will_paginate :)